# Dynamic open graph tags in Single Page Application

Tags: facebook-opengraph, react-helmet

I am trying to inject `op:tags` in my reactjs App. I came across https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet and it dynamically inject the tags ion my index.html header juts like i wanted it. The problem is, it injects the tags at the end of the head and thus was not recognised by facebook debugger [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=POST&path=%3Fscrape%3Dtrue%26id%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fnametalkam.com%2F%23%2Fpost%2F33%2FNigerian%2520Senate%2520Approves%2520President%2520Buhari%27s%2520%2422.7bn%2520Loan%2520Request&version=v5.0). It works when the ogen graph tags appear right in the beginning of the header before the script tags. With reac-helmet however, it injects them at the extreme end. Please how do i best fix this ? I am trying to have article preview on social media and this is failing just because of the arrangement. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, has there been any resolution to this issue?

Comment: @Kayote I decided to rewrite my app in nextjs.

Answer (score 0):

well, I don't think it is because of the arrangement.

As far as I remember FB doesn't execute javascript code in the provided URL.

Facebook’s scraper just looks at the HTML code of your page; it’s not a full-fledged “browser” that would execute any client site code.

with that being said.whatever meta tags you need there it can't be done via JS on the client-side. it must be server-side rendered.

I am not sure what technology you are using to serve this app, but I can assume it is a react app. and it would be easy to handle this via a small express server. that serves the app with the right meta tags in place even.